# Adding Dialog To Splitter Window MFC

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, system32

I'm trying to add a dialog to a splitter window in windows MFC. I've searched around and there are no great solutions that I can see to it right now. Here is roughly what I'm trying to do:

```
if (!m_wndSplitter.CreateStatic(this, 1, 3))
    return FALSE;

if (!m_wndSplitter.CreateView(0, 0, RUNTIME_CLASS(CLeftView), CSize(200, 100), pContext) ||
    !m_wndSplitter.CreateView(0, 1, RUNTIME_CLASS(CLeftView2), CSize(200, 100), pContext) ||
    !m_wndSplitter.CreateDlg(---CODE TO CREATE THE DIALOG---))
{
    m_wndSplitter.DestroyWindow();
    return FALSE;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I would convert your dialog into a CFormView; then it should be easy to use it in a splitter.

Comment: I think you want to use a [CFormView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/353dcby6.aspx) instead.

Comment: See the style of your dialog in the Resource Editor. It should be "Child" and not "Popup". Or programatically, `WS_CHILD` instead of `WS_POPUP`.